# Pyplot - why axline (horizontal line) plots on a different graph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Trying to add an horizontal line with a given value to a line chart with the following code:

```
x = data.index
y = data['AMZN US EQUITY_PE_RATIO']
plt.figure(figsize = (18,6))
plt.axhline(y = 0, color ="green", linestyle ="--")
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle = '-', color = 'b')
```

However the `axhline` always plots on a separate chart. I would like the line to be plotted on the same graph as the line chart. Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Sample data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'TSLA US Equity_PE_RATIO': {Timestamp('2011-08-03 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('2011-08-04 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('2011-08-05 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('2011-08-08 00:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('2011-08-09 00:00:00'): nan}, 'AMZN US EQUITY_PE_RATIO': {Timestamp('2011-08-03 00:00:00'): 92.4934, Timestamp('2011-08-04 00:00:00'): 88.7577, Timestamp('2011-08-05 00:00:00'): 89.2952, Timestamp('2011-08-08 00:00:00'): 85.3304, Timestamp('2011-08-09 00:00:00'): 90.348}})
```

Comment: not able to reproduce on my end (using dummy data `x=[0,1]` and `y=[-2,5]`). are you getting two plots by *only* running these 5 lines?

Comment: I see, I ran a shape() command on my x and y values and they appear to be tuples. I think I will need to format these variables to have them as lists or arrays then?

Comment: please copy-paste the output of `data.head().to_dict()`

Comment: {'TSLA US Equity_PE_RATIO': {Timestamp('2011-08-03 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2011-08-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2011-08-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2011-08-08 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2011-08-09 00:00:00'): nan},
 'AMZN US EQUITY_PE_RATIO': {Timestamp('2011-08-03 00:00:00'): 92.4934,
  Timestamp('2011-08-04 00:00:00'): 88.7577,
  Timestamp('2011-08-05 00:00:00'): 89.2952,
  Timestamp('2011-08-08 00:00:00'): 85.3304,
  Timestamp('2011-08-09 00:00:00'): 90.348}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the issue given your sample `data` and  got it to work by swapping the order of `axhline()` and `plot()`:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='g')
```

Normally there's no issue with plotting `axhline()` first, but here I guess the issue is that `data.index` contains `Timestamp` objects. When `axhline` gets plotted first (on a normal x-axis), there seems to be some issue in mixing it with subsequent date data. The simplest workaround is just to call `plot()` first.

[image: output after calling axhline after plot]